# Embedded: memcpy/memset not used by most CRT startup code ― why?

Tags: c, assembly, embedded

**Context:** 
I'm working on an ARM target, more specifically a Cortex-M4F microcontroller from ST. When working on such platforms (microcontrollers in general), there's obviously no OS; in order to get a working C/C++ "environment" (moreover, to be standard compliant in regard to initialization of variables) there must be some kind of startup code run at reset that does the minimum setup required before explicitly calling `main`. Such startup code, as I hinted, must initialize initialized global and static variables (such as `int foo = 42;`at global scope) and zero-out the other globals (such as `int bar;` at global scope). Then, if necessary, global "ctors" are called.

On a microcontroller, that simply means that the startup code has to copy data from flash to ram for every initialized global (all in section '.data') and clear the others (all in '.bss'). Because I use GCC, I must supply such a startup code and I happily analyzed several startup codes (and its associated linker script!) bundled with numerous examples I've found on the Internet, all using the same demo board I'm developing on.

**Question:**
As stated, I've seen numerous startup codes, and they initialize globals in different ways, some more efficient in term of space and time than others. But they all have something odd in common: they *didn't* use `memset` nor `memcpy`, resorting instead to hand-written loops to do the job. As it appears natural to me to use standard functions when possible (simple "DRY principle"), I tried the following in lieu of the initial hand-written loops:

```
/* Initialize .data section */
ldr r0, DATA_LOAD
ldr r1, DATA_START
ldr r2, DATA_SIZE
bl  memcpy       /* memcpy(DATA_LOAD, DATA_START, DATA_SIZE); */

/* Initialize .bss section */
ldr r0, BSS_START
mov r1, #0
ldr r2, BSS_SIZE
bl  memset       /* memset(BSS_START, 0, BSS_SIZE); */
```

... and it worked perfectly. The space saving are negligible, but it is clearly dead simple now.

So, I thought about it, and I see no reason to do hand-written loops in this case:

- `memcpy` and `memset` are very likely to be linked in the executable anyway, because the programmer would use it directly, or indirectly through another library;
- It is smaller;
- Speed is not a very important factor for startup code, but nevertheless it is likely faster;
- It's nearly impossible to get it wrong.

Any idea why one wouldn't rely on `memcpy` and `memset` for startup code?

Comment: Perhaps for startup code "very likely to be linked in" isn't good enough?

Comment: dwelch: explain yourself. You didn't provide any explanation of why all my assumptions are false. Maybe you could add some more meaningful insights?

Comment: @dwelch : sorry for the flag. And I don't know why you deleted your posts. If I could contact you I'd explain myself. Maybe my question is not very good after all.

Comment: The answer to your question is very simple.  It is a chicken and egg problem, you are trying to use C code to bootstrap C code.  You cant assume that the C code you are using does not require a bootstrap.  Assumptions are not fact, just opinion, if you did not write or personally validate the C code yourself (or even better just write the few lines of asm and have no worries at all) you cannot make ANY statements of FACT about it.  The FACT is the only way to make sure you have resolved the chicken and egg problem is to write the code yourself, the asm is so trivial and small, just use the asm

Comment: This is a very good question, and the answer is certainly not as obvious as some respondents are claiming. While the conclusion is that using memset and memcpy is probably not a good idea in that context, I do not think that these loops need to be written in assembly, on the other hand. SystemInit() is usually written in C, and ST's generated code often invokes it _after_ initializing .bss. and .data. However, some newer ST MCUs require some clocks to be enabled before some parts of internal RAM are even available, and enabling those clocks would typically be done in C in SystemInit()!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whether the standard library is linked at all is decision for the application developer (`--nostdlib` may be used for example), but the start-up code is required, so it cannot make any assumptions.

Further, the purpose of the start-up code is to establish an environment in which C code can run; before that is complete, it is by no means a given that any library code that might reasonably assume a complete run-time environment will run correctly.  For the functions in question this is perhaps not an issue in many cases, but you cannot know that.

The start-up code has to at least establish a stack and initialise static data, in C++ it additionally calls the constructors of global static objects.  The standard library might reasonably assume those are established, so using the standard library *before* then may conceivably result in erroneous behaviour.

Finally you should be clear that the C language and the C standard library are distinct entities.  The language must necessarily be capable of standing alone.

Comment: Clean, succinct answer. That's definitely part of the answer.

Comment: I've added further points - perhaps to the detriment of succinctness and clarity.

Comment: Not at all, it is even better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

I suspect the startup code does not want to make assumptions about the implementation of `memcpy` and such in libc. For example, the implementation of `memcpy` might use a global variable set by libc initialization code to report which cpu extensions are available, in order to provide optimized SIMD copying on machines that support such operations. At the point where the early "crt" startup code is running, the storage for such a global might be completely uninitialized (containing random junk), in which case it would be dangerous to call `memcpy`. Even if making the call *works for you*, it's a consequence of the implementation (or maybe even the unpredictable results of UB...) making it work; this is probably not something the crt code wants to depend on.

Comment: Yup!  Alternatively, `memcpy` or `memset` might use SIMD/FPU instructions that are enabled lazily.  Early in startup, are the handlers in place to deal with the fault that will occur on the first usage of such an instruction?  Are the context save areas that the fault-handler needs to write to set up?

Comment: There's other possible issues too -- the MMU or CPU might not yet be configured to support misaligned access or the transfer widths that are used by the `libc` routines, etc.  There are lots of very good reasons to use only code you directly control early in startup.

Comment: Interesting point. Of course, in such an early stage, nothing is even setup so if it fails, it will probably lock-up in an hardfault handler.

Comment: Actually, on a Cortex-M, you have your vectors and your stack straight off the bat...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is likely to have anything to do with "assumptions about the internal state of memcy/memset", they are unlikely to use any global resources (though I suppose some odd cases exist where they do).

All start up code on microcontrollers is usually written "inline assembler" in this manner, simply because it runs at an early stage in the code, where a stack might not yet be present and the MMU setup may not yet have been executed. Init code therefore doesn't want to risk putting anything on the stack, simple as that. Function calls put things on the stack.

So while this happened to be the initialization code of the static storage copy-down, you are likely to find the same inline assembler in other such init code as well. For example you will likely find some fundamental register setup code written in assembler somewhere before the copy-down, and you will also find the MMU setup in assembler somewhere around there too.

Comment: True about the stack; however, a nice thing about the Cortex M series is that the stack is initialized at reset (the stack pointer is loaded with the first word of the interrupt vector) so it is safe to use the stack directly at program startup. But I understood that in the general case, one wouldn't call any C library at startup because it might rely somehow on initialization.

For the record, I looked at the implementation of memcpy/memset with  objdump and they seem effectively not to use any globals as expected. But of course it doesn't mean that any other implementation doesn't do that.

Comment: +1 In regard to the MMU.  The `memset()` and `memcpy()` may need to be relocatable.  This is easy to guarantee in assembler.  Also, user prefer a fast boot-up over clean code.  Specifically, hardware may not be fully initialized at this point and getting to that code quickly is important in many cases.

Comment: Downvoting because Cortex-M's can have a bootstrap written in C (you just use naive copy-and-set loops to deal with setting up `.data` and `.bss`)

Comment: @LThode That's only because Cortex M sets the MSP from what's stored at address 0 at startup. Most MCUs have an explicit assembler instruction for setting the stack pointer, making it literally impossible to write the whole startup code in C. More advanced architectures require that you set various memory settings before you even know where the stack can be placed - in those cases you need to write the code in inline asm just to prevent the C compiler from generating instructions that use the stack.